# javascript code when multiple checkboxes are checked form fields should appear according to the checkboxes(i tried this using select option method)

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Need check-boxes instead of selection option and multiple check for check boxes according to the checked check boxes form fields should appear.

with a submit button. i have added css a small part, need a full detailed css for this case.

```js
function showHide(elem) {
      if(elem.selectedIndex != 0) {
          //hide the divs
           for(var i=0; i < divsO.length; i++) {
               divsO[i].style.display = 'none';
          }
          //unhide the selected div
          var y = document.getElementsByClassName('input'+elem.value);
          for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
           y[i].style.display = 'block';
          }
         
      }
}
 
window.onload=function() {
    //get the divs to show/hide
    divsO = document.getElementById("main-form").getElementsByTagName('input');
}
```

```css
#main-form input {
   display: none;
  }

  .common {
   margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
```

```html
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="main-form">
  <select onchange="showHide(this)" id="select-field">
   <option value="">Select an option</option>
   <option value="1">flight</option>
   <option value="2">hotel</option>
   <option value="3">travel</option>
  </select>

  <br><br>
  <input type="text" class="input1 common" placeholder="flight">
  <input type="text" class="input1 common" placeholder="flight2">
  <input type="text" class="input1 common" placeholder="flight3">
  
  <input type="text" class="input2 common" placeholder="hotel">
  <input type="text" class="input2 common" placeholder="hotel2">
  
 <input type="text" class="input3 common" placeholder="travel">
  <input type="text" class="input3 common" placeholder="travel2">
  <input type="text" class="input3 common" placeholder="travel3">
  <input type="text" class="input3 common" placeholder="travel4">
 
  
 </form>

 <span id="show"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a checkbox is clicked, it triggers a toggle function which will either hide or show its corresponding textbox inputs.

```js
function toggle(object){
  var input;
  var value = object.getAttribute("value");

  switch(value){
    case "flight":
      input = "input1";
      break;
    case "hotel":
      input = "input2";
      break;
    case "travel":
      input = "input3";
      break;
  }
  
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(input);
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    if (elements[i].style.display == "block") {
      elements[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      elements[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  }
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.common {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

input[type="text"]{
  display:none;
}

button {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="main-form">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" id="flight" value="flight"><label for="flight">Flight</label>

    <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" id="hotel" value="hotel"><label for="hotel">Hotel</label>

    <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" id="travel" value="travel"><label for="travel">Travel</label>

  <br><br>
  <input type="text" class="input1 common" placeholder="flight">
  <input type="text" class="input1 common" placeholder="flight2">
  <input type="text" class="input1 common" placeholder="flight3">
  
  <input type="text" class="input2 common" placeholder="hotel">
  <input type="text" class="input2 common" placeholder="hotel2">
  
 <input type="text" class="input3 common" placeholder="travel">
  <input type="text" class="input3 common" placeholder="travel2">
  <input type="text" class="input3 common" placeholder="travel3">
  <input type="text" class="input3 common" placeholder="travel4">
    
 <button type="submit">Button</button>
  
 </form>

 <span id="show"></span>
```

Comment: thanks mate, also can you make the checkboxes horizontal with css ?

Comment: @Zamil Just remove the <br> tags after the inputs, and if this works just hit the checkmark so people know the question has been answered.

Comment: when ticked hotel i need flight options as well how can i do this?